# GROUP BY clause issue when generating reports

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

I am writing a Java application in IntelliJ using a SQL database for appointment handling. For one portion, I must generate reports of 3 types: Number of appointment types by month, schedule of each consultant, and total number of appointments this year. I previously had this working (and haven't changed anything), and now it is returning errors on the first two report generation:

```
Error Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'U07sym.appointment.start' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

and

```
Error Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'U07sym.appointment.description' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

I have tried a few of the suggestions, but they seem to require 'super' access, and since this is a DB hosted at my school, I don't have that access.

Here is the code for the 1,2 and 3 report generator:

```
public void generateFirstReport() {

    try {
        
        Statement statement = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
        String appointmentTypeQuery = "SELECT description, MONTHNAME(start) as 'Month', COUNT(*) as 'Total' FROM appointment GROUP BY description, MONTH(START)";
        
        ResultSet appointmentQueryResults = statement.executeQuery(appointmentTypeQuery);
        
        StringBuilder parseReport = new StringBuilder();
        
        parseReport.append(String.format("%1$-60s %2$-60s %3$s \n", "Month", "Appointment Type", "Total"));
        parseReport.append(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(163, "-")));
        parseReport.append("\n");
        
        while(appointmentQueryResults.next()) {
            
            parseReport.append(String.format("%1$-56s %2$-60s %3$s \n", appointmentQueryResults.getString("Month"), appointmentQueryResults.getString("description"), appointmentQueryResults.getInt("Total")));
        }
        
        typesOfMonthsText.setText(parseReport.toString());
    }
    
    catch(SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
    
public void generateSecondReport() {
    
    try {
        
        Statement statement = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
        String consultantQueryResults = "SELECT appointment.contact, appointment.description, customer.customerName, start, end " + "FROM appointment JOIN customer ON customer.customerId = appointment.customerId " +
                "GROUP BY appointment.contact, MONTH(start), start";
        
        ResultSet appointmentQueryResults = statement.executeQuery(consultantQueryResults);
        
        StringBuilder parseReport = new StringBuilder();
        parseReport.append(String.format("%1$-45s %2$-45s %3$-45s %4$-45s %5$s \n", "Consultant", "Appointment", "Customer", "Start", "End"));
        parseReport.append(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(163, "-")));
        parseReport.append("\n");
        
        while(appointmentQueryResults.next()) {
            
            parseReport.append(String.format("%1$-37s %2$-50s %3$-35s %4$-35s %5$s \n", 
                appointmentQueryResults.getString("contact"), appointmentQueryResults.getString("description"), appointmentQueryResults.getString("customerName"),
                appointmentQueryResults.getString("start"), appointmentQueryResults.getString("end")));
        }
        
        scheduleOfConsultantText.setText(parseReport.toString());         
        
    }
    catch(SQLException ex) {
       System.out.println("Error " + ex.getMessage()); 
    }       
}

public void generateThirdReport () {
    
    try {
        Statement statement = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
        //"SELECT description, MONTHNAME(start) as 'Month', COUNT(*) as 'Total' FROM appointment GROUP BY description, MONTH(START)";
        String appointmentQueryResults = "SELECT YEAR(start) as 'Year', COUNT(*) as 'Total' FROM appointment GROUP BY YEAR(start)";
        
        ResultSet yearlyQueryResults = statement.executeQuery(appointmentQueryResults);
        
        StringBuilder parseReport = new StringBuilder();
        parseReport.append(String.format("%1$-50s %2$-50s \n", "Year", "Total"));
        parseReport.append(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(163, "-")));
        parseReport.append("\n");
        
        while(yearlyQueryResults.next()) {
            
            parseReport.append(String.format("%1$-50s %2$-50s \n", yearlyQueryResults.getString("Year"), yearlyQueryResults.getString("Total")));
        }
        
        totalAppointmentsThisYearText.setText(parseReport.toString());
    }
    
    catch(SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: The Query is not proper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mysql is currently supporting only only_full_group_by means all the columns present in select clause must be in group functions like sum, avg, max etc. or in group clause.

To resolve this you have to change your mysql setting.

If you are using mysql workbench in `Windows` then goto `Edit >> Preferences` and then select `MySql` under `Modeling`

See below screenshot for reference.

[image]

After that remove only_full_group_by from `MSQ_MODE to be used in generated scripts` textbox and click ok. Then restart you mysql.

And if you are using Linux then connect to mysql from Linux terminal.

Execute below script.

```
SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```